# Routing Angular 8 integrated with CSHTML page

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular8, asp.net-web-api-routing

As i have integrated in **HomeController** inside its **Index.cshtml** after using `ng build --deploy-url=~/LogisticAppUI/dist/` then copying from **dist** the code of **Index.html** and pasting it inside **Index.cshtml**, here is the code below for **Index.cshtml**.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Color Admin</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body detect-scroll (onScroll)="handleScroll($event)">
    <app>
        <!-- begin #page-loader -->
        <div id="page-loader" class="fade show"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
        <!-- end #page-loader -->
    </app>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/runtime.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/polyfills.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/styles.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/vendor.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/LogisticAppUI/dist/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now as the page is working correctly it logins in as required here is a screenshot for the page which i'm accessing after clicking **Staff Members**. 
[image: Route]
Now if i again hit the **Url** above it shows me this.
[image]
As i know it's trying to access by **Controller** name but it does not exists in the **API** know i only want to access it inside **Angular** itself if i try to hit the **URL** again rather than searching it in the **WebApi**, it should only work when i use for ***POST*** and ***GET*** which is correctly working like this below.

```
StaffInfoAdd(_Staff: Staff,ProfilePicFile: File) {

        const fData = new FormData();
        fData.append('Id', _Staff.Id == null ? '' : _Staff.Id.toString());
        fData.append('FirstName', _Staff.FirstName);
        fData.append('SendEmail', _Staff.SendEmail.toString());
        fData.append('SendPhone', _Staff.SendPhone.toString());
        fData.append('Password', _Staff.Password);

        if(ProfilePicFile != null){
            fData.append('FileUpload', ProfilePicFile, ProfilePicFile.name);
        }
        const hdrs = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Disposition', 'mulipart/form-data');
        this.http.post(HostedPathConst.HostedPath + `Staff/Register`, fData, {headers:hdrs})
            .subscribe(this.Success, this.Error);
        this.messageStaffSource.next(_Staff);        
    }

    GetStaff(): Promise<any> {
        const promise = this.http.get(HostedPathConst.HostedPath + `Staff/GetStaff`).toPromise();
        return promise;
    }
```

This is working fine when i use independently for **Angular 8** in **Visual Studio Code** but when i integrate it with **Visual Studio 2019 with API** starts searching for **Controller** name when hitting **Url**.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you need to add `useHash: true` in app-routing.module.ts It should look like code below.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you its working but how can i use it on <a href="javascript: onclick=location.href='/StaffMembers'" class="btn btn-light text-grey btn-lg m-t-20 p-10">Cancel</a> i have used #/StaffMembers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Used routerLink as like this <a [routerLink]="['/StaffMembers']" class="btn btn-light text-grey btn-lg m-t-20  p-10">Cancel</a> it worked